# Integrating a WordPress website to my Data Management (CRUD) System

Tags: php, database, wordpress, system

My colleague and I have a project and we've decided that I will create the Data Management System and he will do the WordPress site and just integrate it later using the database of WordPress.

However, when we found out that WordPress' database is complicated/very general and NOT all of the fields in my ERD are there, we encountered a problem integrating.

May I ask if anyone of you here has experienced this kind of situation? Or is there any way that you know how to integrate data from website to the system?

The main goal would be this:
1. A user will order through the WordPress website
2. It will then reflect on the System and will be displayed there, its details, price, description, etc. for the admin to see.

We are using the following tools:
Website - WordPress 4.8
System - Laravel 5.2
Jquery and AJAX Requests

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: why not ditch wp and go full laravel?

Comment: how are you passing the data from wp to laravel?

Comment: The client wants the website to be WordPress

Comment: how are you passing the data from wp to laravel?

Comment: We are currently having different databases for that. So currently, I'm working on my local database. We'll try to merge it tomorrow

Comment: so you will run wp and laravel on the same db?

Comment: Yes we will. We want to connect it so that when someone orders, it will reflect in my system

Comment: so what's the problem? you want to connect wp to a laravel db or laravel to a wp db?

Comment: Connect Laravel DB to the WP DB

Comment: you said that you will have only one db  now you have 2?